# the X event after next...Th

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adverbs

Is it grammatically correct to say "at the steering committee meeting after next"?

The idea is that there are meetings every two weeks, but the intention is for something to be presented not at the next steering committee (i.e. in two weeks), but at the following one (i.e. in four weeks).

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine, grammatically. It is akin to saying, "on the Monday after next".

Answer (score -1):

That sounds perfectly alright to me. But you could also say:

***at the next but one meeting of the steering committee on...***.

I would then specify the date, just to be on the safe side.